# Javascript: parse a string to Date as LOCAL time zone

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I have a string representing the current time: `2015-11-24T19:40:00`. How do I parse this string in Javascript to get a Date represented by this string as the **LOCAL TIME**?  **Due to some restriction, I cannot use the library `moment`, but jquery is allowed. I know that someone has asked this question before, but the answer used `moment`**

For example, if I run the script in California, then this string would represent 7PM pacific time, but if I run the script in NY then this string would represent Eastern Time?

I tried the following but Chrome and Firefox give me different results:

```
var str = "2015-11-24T19:40:00";
var date = new Date(str);
```

Chrome consumes it as **UTC** time (`Tue Nov 24 2015 11:40:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`),

but Firefox consumes it as my local **PACIFIC** time (`Tue Nov 24 2015 19:40:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`)

I tried adding "Z" to `str`, like this `var date = new Date(str+"Z");`, then both browsers give me UTC time. Is there any similar letter to `"Z"` which tells all browsers (at least chrome, Firefox and Safari) to parse the string as local time zone?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Parsing of date strings using the Date constructor or Date.parse (which are essentially the same thing) is strongly recommended against.

If Date is called as a function and passed an ISO 8601 format date string without a timezone (such as 2015-11-24T19:40:00), you may get one of the following results:

1. Pre ES5 implementaitons may treat it as anything, even NaN (such as IE 8)
2. ES5 compliant implementations will treat it as UTC timezone
3. ECMAScript 2015 compliant implementations will treat it as local (which is consistent with ISO 8601)

A Date object has a time value which is UTC, and an offset based on system settings. When you send a Date to output, what you see is usually the result of *Date.prototype.toString*, which is an implementation dependent, human readable string representing the date and time, usually in a timezone based on system settings.

The best way to parse date strings is to do it manually. If you are assured that the format is consistent and valid, then parsing an ISO format string as a local date is as simple as:

```js
/*  @param {string} s - an ISO 8001 format date and time string
**                      with all components, e.g. 2015-11-24T19:40:00
**  @returns {Date} - Date instance from parsing the string. May be NaN.
*/
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5]);
}

document.write(parseISOLocal('2015-11-24T19:40:00'));
```

Note that parsing of ISO strings using Date.parse only accepts UTC, it does not accept any other timezone designation (noting the above behaviour if it's missing).

Comment: as a side question, does `new Date()` always return a local current time? If not, how can I get the current local time?  At least to me test it does for Chrome and Firefox. Basically, I need to get the difference (in seconds) between the current time and a given time represented by the string, like `"2015-11-24T19:40:00"`

Comment: As above, `new Date()` returns a Date object with its time value set to the current UTC time and an offset based on system settings. How that is presented is determined by the method called: [*toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring), [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring), [*toUTCString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring), [*toLocaleTimeString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) etc.

Comment: I am working with two types of Date object.

new Date("2000-01-01")

new Date(2000, 0, 1)
In the first type, timeZoneOffset was added to the date but not in the second type. How can I identify the timezoneOffset is added or not to the date object?

Comment: @KesavanSubramaniam—the first is parsed as UTC, the second is treated as local. Both are resolved to UTC. Date objects don’t have an offset, they are UTC and use the system offset to get local values.

Answer (score 15):

A variation on RobG's terrific answer.

> **Note** that this will require that you run bleeding edge JavaScript as
> it relies on the arrow notation and spread operator.

```
function parseDateISOString(s) {
  let ds = s.split(/\D/).map(s => parseInt(s));
  ds[1] = ds[1] - 1; // adjust month
  return new Date(...ds);
}
```

Note that this doesn't take into account if the date/time given is in any timezone. It will assume local time. You can change `new Date` for `Date.UTC` to assume UTC.

There are technical reasons for why you would write you code like this. For example, here we apply the correct number of arguments, with their corresponding expected type. It's true that the Date constructor will turn strings into numbers but what could be happening is that there's a deoptimization taking place where the optimized code is expecting a number but sees a string and takes a slower path. Not a big deal but I try to write my JavaScript to avoid such things. We also won't be indexing outside the bounds of the array if less than 6 components can be found in the string which is also one of those things you can do in JavaScript but it has subtle deoptimization caveats.

Comment: @IAfanasov sorry, I think you have to elaborate a bit more. I don't understand what you trying to say.

Comment: The use of *map* to convert to number is redundant.

Answer (score -1):

Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time.

I also have a much faster way than using the string.split() because we already know where the numbers are:

```
return new Date(Number(date.substring(0, 4)), Number(date.substring(5, 7))-1, 
                Number(date.substring(8, 10)), Number(date.substring(11, 13)), 
                Number(date.substring(14, 16)), Number(date.substring(17, 19)));
```

This will work with and/or without the 'T' and 'Z' strings and still has decent performance. I added the explicit Number conversion (faster and better than parseInt) so this also compiles in TypeScript.
Number

Comment: You can't ignore the Z as it differentiates whether the values should be parsed as UTC or local.