# Date issuse while adding 1 day after

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I had one logic issue while date .

```
    Date:<input id="txtDate" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Fill Follow Date" />
Follow Date:<input id="follow_Date" type="text" />
```

Add Script

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker();
    $('#follow_Date').datepicker();
});

function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;

    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());

    var dd = newdate.getDate()+1;
    var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

For today "31-03-2016" the follow date show "32-03-2016". But its show the 01-04-2016. Do you have any other logic for to over come this error. 
We had the options like "makemytrips" hotel page. makemytrip.com/hotels here you can see the number of nigths. same concept i used for my site

Comment: Just `newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);` Do not add it later..

Comment: Don't use the Date constructor to parse strings, it's extremely unreliable. Manually parse strings, use a library or a [*simple function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908299/javascript-parse-a-string-to-date-as-local-time-zone/33909265#33909265).

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing a date addition, instead a numerical addition. `getDate()` returns a <strike>string</strike> number value of `31` to which if you add 1 you will get `32`, what is wrong in that, then you are doing a string concatenating which is causing the problem.

Instead you can use the [datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker), and [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) apis

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $date = $('#txtDate').datepicker();
  var $follow = $('#follow_Date').datepicker();
  $('#fill-follow').click(function() {
    var date = $date.datepicker('getDate');
    if (date) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      //date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
      $follow.datepicker('setDate', date)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Date:
<input id="txtDate" type="text" />
<input type="button" id="fill-follow" value="Fill Follow Date" />Follow Date:
<input id="follow_Date" type="text" />
```

Comment: Ya rayon. We had the options like "makemytrips"  hotel page.
http://www.makemytrip.com/hotels
here you can see the number of nigths. same concept i used for my site

Comment: Wow, 3 libraries for an extremely simple task. The code throws "$ is not defined" for me in Chrome.

Comment: @RobG If you look at the question, OP is already using jQuery UI... so why not use those apis to do the task

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 1 to the `getDate()` result, then call `setDate()` on it:

```
function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;

    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 1);

    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + y;
    document.getElementById('follow_Date').value = someFormattedDate;
}
```

Also, reading your code, I wonder why you create a date twice :

```
    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
```

Couldn't you just combine these into one line ?

```
    var newdate = new Date(tt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your logic like below

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

To format the date:

```
var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
```