# PhantomJS Local ISO Date off

Tags: angular, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have some tests for an Angular 2 app that pass in when run in Firefox but fail in PhantomJS. In the test I'm checking that a date is set properly. I feed in a local iso date string in the form "2017-07-20T14:20". The date portion is set properly but the time is off. I'm running the test in Mountain Time zone (-6:00 UTC) so the time is coming through as 08:20. Is there a shim or set up config I may be missing.

Here is some code:

In my customDate class file

```
public startTime: string;

public setDate(date: string) {
    let date:Date = new Date(date);
    this.startTime = date.getHours() + ':';
    if (date.getMinutes() < 10) {
        this.startTime += date.getMinutes() + '0';
    } else {
        this.startTime += date.getMinues();
    }
 }
```

In my test file

```
it('should pass') {
    let testDate = new customDate();
    testDate.setDate('2017-07-20T14:20');
    expect(testDate.startTime).toBe('14:00'); <-- this is failing it's comeing through as ('8:00')
}
```

Comment: I think that the time you are inputting is UTC unless you use a [time offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When researching a similar problem with older versions of Chrome and Safari parsing a local date time string as UTC we found this solutions: [Javascript: parse a string to Date as LOCAL time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908299/javascript-parse-a-string-to-date-as-local-time-zone) . It turns out that PhantomJS uses ES5 and thus the date time strings are parsed as UTC not local. The solution in the link explains whats happening and how to work around it.