# angularjs - confusion with date formats

Tags: angularjs, date, momentjs

I am super confused with date formats and need some clarifications.  I am trying to pre-populate a form with a date and have set $scope.selectedDate = c.data.Appt.enrolled.start_date;

In my console, c.data.Appt.enrolled.start_date is a string:

[image]

However, when I set $scope.selectedDate to that, nothing shows up.

Conversely, if I add new Date in front

```
(new Date(c.data.Appt.enrolled.start_date))
```

a date shows up, but it is one day before (April 24, 2018).

In addition to that, when I try to insert the "new Date" version into a function (even though it isn't the correct date), I get a warning in the console saying "Moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release."

Can someone explain how I should format the dates so I: 1) get the correct date and not one day prior and 2) am able to plug it into a function without getting that warning?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: parse a string to Date as LOCAL time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908299/javascript-parse-a-string-to-date-as-local-time-zone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the date is a string with no time zone information (just the date) JavaScript Date parser will treat it as universal(UTC, which is in Greenwich Mean Time) time at `00:00` hours. Then it will subtract the offset of your locale's timezone in hours, and will result in the date being a few hours before or after the day you actually want. This is a common point of confusion.

The best way to solve this is to parse the date manually:

```
function localDate(dateString) {
  var d = dateString.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2]);
}
```

See this question for more information: [Javascript: parse a string to Date as LOCAL time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908299/javascript-parse-a-string-to-date-as-local-time-zone)

Moment.js gives that warning because it's considered bad practice to rely on the string parsing that `new Date()` does since it will have different results in different browsers (IE\Firefox\Etc.). It's more cross-browser friendly to build the date using this form: `new Date(year, month, day)`. (Note that the month starts at zero, not 1)